# Unreasonably deleted move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, move-semantics

I have a class with explicitely deleted copy constructor named, let's say, `NonCopyable`. Then there's a class `Base1` with a member of type `NonCopyable`. And another class `Base2` with `Base1` as parent. And finally - a `Derivative` class which parent is `Base2`.

Since `NonCopyable` is non-copyable, it's obvious that `Base1`, `Base2` and `Derivative` will be also non-copyable. But it seems like there's been also move constructor (and assign operator) deleted.

Test it here:

- [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f55648a83a53211f)
- [MSVC](http://rextester.com/HAX71321)

Following line gives those errors:
`Derived d1, d2 = std::move(d1);`

> **GCC:** 'Derived::Derived(Derived&&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
>      class Derived :
>   *the rest of errors just claims that `Base1` and `Base2` copy ctors are implicitly deleted which is not weird*
>
> **MSVC:** error C2280: 'Derived::Derived(const Derived &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

In provided links there's also commented lines which gives similar errors. Please uncomment them to see more errors I'd like to show you (e.g. with `remove_if` uncommented it complains about deleted move *(on GCC)* /copy *(on MSVC)* assign operator).
What I want to achieve is make Derivative (and its bases also) moveable, but not copyable.

I'm working with Visual Studio 2015 and getting exactly the same error as in the msvc link I provided, but I'm not sure what version of MSVC is used to compile on *rextester.com*.

I'm pasting the code also here at the request of @Richard Critten:

```
    class NonCopyable
    {
    public:
       NonCopyable() { }
       NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &) = delete;
       NonCopyable & operator=(const NonCopyable &) = delete;
       NonCopyable(NonCopyable &&) { }
       NonCopyable & operator=(NonCopyable &&) { return *this; }
    };

     class Base1
     {
     public:
          virtual ~Base1() = default;

     private:
          NonCopyable m;
     };

     class Base2 :
        public Base1
     {
     public:
          virtual ~Base2() = default;
     };

     class Derived :
        public Base2
     {
     };



int main()
{
    std::vector<Derived> v;
    //std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const Derived &) { return true; });
    //v.emplace_back();
    Derived d1, d2 = std::move(d1);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code here I am allergic to random links.  Also if this question proves to be useful having the code here is better for search and we don't have to worry that it will be deleted from the linked sites.

Comment: Please [read about when the implicit move-constructor is deleted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_move_constructor).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't think that `Derived` fits in any of these criteria. But if you see my mistake, please tell me where it is.

Comment: @Criss: Some experimentation indicates that it's necessary for both `Base` and `Base2` to declare their move constructors, but `Derived` can do with the defaults. I don't know exactly why.

Comment: The problem can be [seen with `Base1` already](http://rextester.com/FAFW16944); the rest is an unnecessary complication. Move constructor for `Base1` is not generated because it has a user-declared destructor.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf no, explicitly defining `Base1`'s and `Base2`'s move ctors doesn't change anything. At least on msvc :/  
@IgorTandetnik Yea, apparently. I'm struggling with this already a few days...

Comment: It does change something for me - the error message. It now complains about the lack of default constructor. That one is no longer implicitly declared as soon as any other constructor is explicitly declared. And of course, without a default constructor `Derived d1;` doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, okay, I probably did something wrong while testing. It actually works - my fault.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **[class.copy]/9** If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
>
> (9.4) — `X` does not have a user-declared destructor.

`Base1` has a user-declared destructor, so no move constructor for it. And copy constructor is implicitly declared as deleted due to non-copyable member. So `Base1` can be neither copied nor moved, and of course `Base2` and `Derived` together with it.

Comment: Huh. It works! But... I must have `Base1` and `Base2` destructors virtual anyway. So... the only option is to explicitly define move constructors?
Also - can you provide a link to where you get the quote from?

Comment: You can explicitly define them as defaulted. Then you would also need to explicitly define a default constructor. The quote comes from the C++14 standard draft: https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard

Comment: Now I finally remember. This was Scott Meyers' doing. He noticed the problem with default moving from a class with class invariant (indicated by having a user defined destructor) and posted about it in comp.std.c++ and comp.lang.c++. There was some discussion and the proposed rules were amended.